# ImapX can't login to local hMailServer from my application, but Thunderbird can

Tags: c#, imap, hmail-server, imapx

I have a local hMailServer instance, which I would like to connect to. I've successfully used ImapX for example for connecting to GMail or different mail servers, but simply cannot get the authentication work for this simple local hMailServer. I've spent about 2 hours now with it and tried quite everything.

If I try to log in with the same accoutn with Thunderbird, everything is fine. When my application tries to log in using ImapX, the server log show invalid username or password. Thunderbird is configureed for non-secure connection, using plain password, just as ImapX (I guess). Here are the logs, first with ImapX, second with Thunderbird.

**With ImapX:**

```
"IMAPD" 3268 3 "2014-12-21 00:32:05.098" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"IMAPD" 2180 3 "2014-12-21 00:32:05.114" "RECEIVED: IMAPX1 CAPABILITY"
"IMAPD" 2180 3 "2014-12-21 00:32:05.114" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]IMAPX1 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 3268 3 "2014-12-21 00:32:05.114" "RECEIVED: IMAPX2 LOGIN "xx@xxxxx.com" ***"
"IMAPD" 3268 3 "2014-12-21 00:32:05.129" "SENT: IMAPX2 NO Invalid user name or password."
```

**With Thunderbird:**

```
"IMAPD" 3268 4 "2014-12-21 00:39:50.769" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"IMAPD" 3268 4 "2014-12-21 00:39:50.769" "RECEIVED: 1 capability"
"IMAPD" 3268 4 "2014-12-21 00:39:50.769" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]1 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 3268 4 "2014-12-21 00:39:50.769" "RECEIVED: 3 login "xx@xxxxx.com" ***"
"IMAPD" 3268 4 "2014-12-21 00:39:50.769" "SENT: 3 OK LOGIN completed"
"IMAPD" 3268 4 "2014-12-21 00:39:50.769" "RECEIVED: 4 select "INBOX""
```

I've rechecked several times, that the exact same passwords are sent, no misspell or so. The only difference I see in the log is letter casing, but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

In my C# code I simply call `_client.Login(userName, password)`, nothing special, no any non-default configuration for ImapX.

Has anyone any ideas what could cause this, or where else should I test something or have a look?

Comment: hMailServer is insecure junk. I tried to use it as a quick-and-dirty solution on Windows because I did not want to set up a Postfix/Dovecot/SpamAssassin system. It was a big mistake. It suffered race problems internally, and it could not consume its own backup during a restore. I had to set up a Windows task to stop and start the service every 15 minutes because the service would hang when Apple and Linux clients would make too many concurrent connections. It also does *not* support `STARTTLS` extension, so other MTAs contacting it can only transfer messages in plain text.

Comment: @jww I didn't have any problems so far, probably I'm lucky, I will consider your points. However in this case the problem was at my side, just after I posted the qestion I finally found the cause, it was really silly. I will post the answer, it can be useful to someone maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out right after posting the question (as usual), that in the password which is stored in a database, I had ONE trailing space by accident. Because the password is removed from hMailServer log, I could not figure it out. After I called `String.Trim` before sending the login information, the login was succesful.

Such a silly bug, I hope someone can benefit from this post in the future.

Comment: You should accept your answer so this question shows up as answered.

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminding me. I could not accept due to the 2 day limit, and then preparing for christmas had a higher priority :)